# Get file extension native method

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using MVS 2010, C++ program without using CRT.
Implementation of finding extension of file:

```
LPWSTR findExtension(LPCWSTR fileName) 
{
    int pos = findchr(fileName, L".");
    if (pos != -1) {
        int lenght = lstrlenW(fileName);
        wchar_t* extension = (wchar_t*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, lenght - pos + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght - pos; i++)
        {
            extension[i] = fileName[pos + 1 + i];
        }
        extension[lenght - pos] = 0;
        LPWSTR ret = extension;

        return ret;
    }
}
```

There are problems. Sometimes it can crash application. And memory leak.
How to fix this issues?

Comment: do you have a stacktrace ?

Comment: What is `findchr`? Show the code that calls `findExtension`. Show a [mcve]. Read this: [ask]

Comment: I think `lenght` is the number of wide characters not the number of bytes. Also that  should be spelled `length`

Comment: Do you call `HeapFree` at some point? But anyway, the memory leak might come from memory corruption, see drescherjm's answer below.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: what extension does `findExtension("Foo.bar.txt")` return?

Comment: @Jabberwocky he should always find the last part of dot.

Comment: *C++ program without using CRT* -- If your concern about not using the CRT is to have a small footprint, why are you using dynamic allocation here?  Why not return the position of where the extension starts, and let the client decide whether they want to create a new field?  Your program makes decisions about memory allocation that need not be made -- that should be up to the client program calling your function.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using them - MVS is the MVS mainframe operating system which this question is NOT about.

Comment: This function's return value is *indeterminate* if there is no `.` found in the input string. Also, why is this function even allocating any memory at all? Why not simply return a pointer to the extension inside the input string? Also, why implement this function at all? Look at [`PathFindExtensionW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindextensionw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
int lenght = lstrlenW(fileName);
```

`lenght` is the number of wide characters not the number of bytes. So you allocate a too small buffer here:

```
wchar_t* extension = (wchar_t*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, lenght - pos + 1);
```

You need to use this instead:

```
wchar_t* extension = (wchar_t*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), NULL, sizeof(wchar_t) * (lenght - pos + 1));
```

Comment: Note that the following header has many functions to deal with path manipulations: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/)

Comment: You may be interested in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindextensionw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathfindextensionw)

Answer (score -1):

`HeapAlloc()` function will allocate memory on heap. When you're not using the heap memory block you need to free it. You can use:
    `BOOL HeapFree( HANDLE hHeap,DWORD dwFlags,_Frees_ptr_opt_ LPVOID lpMem);`

Even though you're in a `{....}` module, **heap** will not behave just like the **stack** that it will automatically `FREE` its memory. The more you reuse the function the more it will allocate memory to the heap and your `private memory size`(see task manager) will grow bigger and bigger. And by the time the OS can't give you memory it will suddenly crash.

Not freeing **heap** memory after using is bad if your program is running a long period (worst case if infinite time) and always perform processes.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Stack Overflow is not a forum, where you share opinions. It's a Q&A site.